# HierarchyId in KendoUI TreeView

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, hierarchyid, kendo-treeview

i am new to KendoUI so i was wondering if/how i can use data represented with the new HierarchyId datatype in my sql server database in my KendoUI TreeView.
Are there any suggestions on how to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have chosen the default value for [`loadOnDemand`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#loadondemand-booleandefault), I would suggest to map the `id` of the node in one column (`id`) and the text in another (`text`) and the `id` of the parent node in another (`pid`).

So the following tree:

```
root -+- Node1
      +- Node2 -+- Node2.1
      |         +- Node2.2
      +- Node3
```

Would be stored as:

```
ID      PID     TEXT
------- ------- --------
root    null    Root
node1   root    Node1
node2   root    Node2
node3   root    Node3
node2.1 node2   Node2.1
node2.2 node2   Node2.2
```

Each time that KendoUI wants to `expand` a node, if will send a request with the `id` of the node being expanded

Example:

```
http://myserver/getChildren?id=node2.2
```

Which selects the sub-nodes of the node Node2.2 (which `id` is node2.2). And the SQL statement would be:

```
SELECT ID, TEXT FROM KENDO_TREE WHERE (PID = 'node2.2');
```